# summarizing fields from three table

Tags: sql-server

I have three table and I need to summarize fields from table pay and pay2 by code column from table students.
I wrote a query but the first table (here is table pay) is correct answer but second table (here is table pay2) is every record repeated to first table record count and answer is wrong !

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUDENTS.CODE, 
                STUDENTS.NAME, 
                Sum(Cast (PAY.PRICE AS INT))  AS payTotal, 
                Sum(Cast (PAY2.PRICE AS INT)) AS pay2Total 
FROM   STUDENTS 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PAY 
                    ON STUDENTS.CODE = PAY.CODE 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PAY2 
                    ON STUDENTS.CODE = PAY2.CODE 
GROUP  BY STUDENTS.CODE, 
          STUDENTS.NAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    students.code,
    students.name,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(cast (pay.price AS INT))
        FROM
            pay
        WHERE
            students.code=pay.code 
    ) AS payTotal,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(cast(pay2.price AS INT))
        FROM
            pay2
        WHERE
            students.code=pay2.code 
    ) AS pay2Total
FROM
    students
```